# Force compilation of Ruby extensions when installing a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to force the compilation of a Ruby extensions locally, instead of using any sort of packaged version, when installing a gem?

Comment: Which gem, for example?

Comment: pg or nokogiri, they both have native extensions and they both have packages for windows. I want to build them locally on Windows.

Comment: You can download pg gem file and then use `gem install --local /path/to/file.gem` to install pg locally.